# Logging Values with Google Sheet Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to write a script that logs a column's values every 7 days. Is this possible through Google Sheet scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It is possible using `getValues()` and `setValues()`. Write the script and set it to run on trigger every 7 days.